# Could not get Resource guava.jar Tag mismatch

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

**I am getting this error during gradle build.I am using android studio 2.1 beta 2.**

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not download guava.jar (com.google.guava:guava:19.0)
   > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/guava/guava/19.0/guava-19.0.jar'.
      > Tag mismatch!
```

**I have tried adding guava dependency in build.gradle but still it is showing same error. This is my build.gradle**

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mappr.co"
        minSdkVersion 12
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 9
        versionName "5.5"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    provided 'org.parceler:parceler:0.2.7'

    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient-android', version: '4.3.5.1'


    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3') {
        exclude module: "httpclient"
    }

    **compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'**

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.17'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:0.2.7'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.0.9'
    compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
}
```